# Failure to install bcrypt

Tags: node.js

appreciate any help.
Working on x64 Windows 10 running node v5.9.0
My package file has dependency: "bcrypt": "^0.8.0",
This error happens when I run 'node server'
Aware that bcrypt has been complicated for windows but I have installed python, C++ compiler and all that was required so slightly confused now.
[image: Error on console]

Answer (score 0):

I actually just figured out where my issue was. I forgot to make global variables. For anyone else, [this link is of awesome help!](https://www.robertkehoe.com/2015/03/fix-node-gyp-rebuild-error-on-windows/)